# Validation vue laravel, change text-error

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I loaded a package "Vue Laravel Validator" to validate in vue.
Example:

```
<input id="name"  v-validate="'min:6|max:46|required'" type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required v-model="title">

                <div class="help-block with-errors" v-show="errors.has('title')">В название:
                    <a> {{ errors.first('title') }}</a>
                </div>
```

And display error: `The title field must be at least 6 characters.`
How can i change text in error? 
For example: `"the title only 6 characters"`

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom message in Laravel validation (server side)

```
public function save(Request $request){
  $validation = $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|min:3|max:32'
  ],[
    'name.required' => 'Name is required',
    'name.min' => 'Name should be greater than 3 characters',
    'name.max' => 'Name should be less than 32 characters'
  ]);

  if($validation->fails()){
     return response()->json($validation->errors()->all());
  }
}
```

Comment: exuce me , write in post controller this?

Comment: Yes, where you are using these form values

Comment: i used to use v-validate="" (in vue) , how can i send it (via controller) in vue?

Comment: Check again, I have edited code. It will validate and return JSON in case of errors ```if($validation->fails()){
     return response()->json($validation->errors()->all());
  }```

Comment: If you really are using `Vue-Laravel-Validator` then it is doing an ajax post: https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Laravel-Validator/blob/master/src/form.js#L40 so Sateesh solution is correct.  Unless you're using vee-validate, which is something else and not what was asked.  I upvoted Sateesh solution.